# I cannot reach variable in the inner if else statements

Tags: python

I am working on some project. I have C++  and Java background but I don't have python background. 
I have given txt file like below:

> G1 X000 Y00
>   X00
>   Z000
>   G0 X121.212 Z5.32
>   X0.00 Y3.000

I need to add G.. to the next lines until it sees new G.. . It can be G1  or G0 or G5 etc .. so result will be like below

> G1 X000 Y00
>   G1 X00
>   G1 Z000
>   G0 X121.212 Z5.32
>   G0 X0.00 Y3.000

My code is below.

```
command = ""
with open('Model.ngc', 'r') as f:
    with open("out.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            if line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
                f1.write(line)
            elif line.startswith('M', 0, 1):
                f1.write(line)
            else:
                command = line.split(' ', 1)[0]
                if command == 'G0' or command == 'G00':
                    command = 'G00'
                elif command == 'G1' or command == 'G01':
                    command = 'G01'
                elif command == 'G2' or command == 'G02':
                    command = 'G02'
                elif command == 'G3' or command == 'G03':
                    command = 'G03'

                if (line.startswith('G0 ', 0, 3) or line.startswith('G1 ', 0, 3) or line.startswith('G2 ', 0, 3) or
                    line.startswith('G3 ', 0, 3) or line.startswith('G4 ', 0, 3) or line.startswith('G5 ', 0, 3) or
                    line.startswith('G6 ', 0, 3) or line.startswith('G7 ', 0, 3) or line.startswith('G8 ', 0, 3) or
                    line.startswith('G9 ', 0, 3)):

                    if command == 'G00':
                        f1.write(line.replace('G0', 'G00'))
                    elif command == 'G01':
                        f1.write(line.replace('G1', 'G01'))
                    elif command == 'G02':
                        f1.write(line.replace('G2', 'G02'))
                    elif command == 'G03':
                        f1.write(line.replace('G3', 'G03'))
                    elif command == 'G04':
                        f1.write(line.replace('G4', 'G04'))
                    elif command == 'G05':
                        f1.write(line.replace('G5', 'G05'))
                    elif command == 'G06':
                        f1.write(line.replace('G6', 'G06'))
                    print(command)
                else:
                    # print(line)

                    if ( line.startswith('G00') or line.startswith('G01') or line.startswith('G02') or
                         line.startswith('G03') or line.startswith('G04') or line.startswith('G05') or
                         line.startswith('G06') or line.startswith('G07') or line.startswith('G08') or line.startswith('G09')):
                        # Because it can be already converted
                        f1.write(line)
                    else:
                        f1.write(command + line)
```

I am trying to get G1 or G0 from previous line and assign to ***command***. It works. when I try to reach in the last **else statement** it show that my **command**
variable is empty and I don't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Split each line and check if the first word starts with G. If so, then have that as the word to be added as prefix `pre`. 
If the line doesn't have the prefix then, join the stored word along with the line with space!!

```
pre=""
for  line  in f1.read().splitlines():
    word = line.split()
    if word and word[0] and word[0][0]=="G":
        pre=word[0]
    else:
        line = " ".join([pre, line])
    print line
```

Output

```
G1 X000 Y00
G1 X00
G1 Z000
G0 X121.212 Z5.32
G0 X0.00 Y3.000
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it is not working.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NgcToGcode.py", line 6, in <module>
    if word[0] and word[0][0] == "G":
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: can you check if the line read is right from your side?  Coz, I tried in console and only then have shared the answer here! This snippet should come right after `with open("out.txt", "w") as f1:`

Comment: or there is a case when the line read is empty! I've added the edit for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for 'G'in string, substring it and use it to lines which don't have.
I tried in my way,

```
with open('newfile.txt','r') as f:
Gval = 'G0'
newlines=[]
for line in f:
    if 'G' in line:
        Gval = line[line.index('G'):line.index(' ')]
        newlines.append(line)
    else:
        l = Gval+' '+line
        newlines.append(l)
f.close()
newf = open('filenew.txt','w')
for item in newlines:
    newf.write("%s"%item)   
newf.close()
```